# Need help for Video.Thumbnails API

Tags: android

I am trying to use the MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails API to create a thumbnail bitmap for a video file. My question is how to specify the API to create a thumbnail of the beginning of the video instead of the end of the video.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the MediaStore.View.Thumbnails API doesn't allow you to specify at what point in the video your thumbnail is generated from.